# JSON_VALUE cannot get the filtered results

Tags: sql-server, json

I am trying to make one of the features of MS SQL 2016 - JSON_VALUE work for me...

I have a collection of objects in JSON format stored in one of the fields in the DB for each record.

Here is an example:

```
[{"CommunicatorType":0,"UserName":"SkypeUser"},{"CommunicatorType":1,"UserName":"FaceUser"}]
```

What I am trying to do is to perform the search inside that column that holds that information:

```
"SELECT * from Students WHERE JSON_VALUE(CommunicatorsJson, '$.UserName') LIKE 'SkypeUser'"
```

Zero result...

If I use just one object as JSON:

```
{"CommunicatorType":0,"UserName":"SkypeUser"}
```

It works, no problem... But it refuses to go through the collection in one record and check that particular field for a value in the search for a record.  How do I have to format the search? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a subquery to access the elements in the column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Students 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM OPENJSON(CommunicatorsJson)
    WITH (UserName VARCHAR(200) '$.UserName')
    WHERE UserName = 'SkypeUser'
)
```

Comment: Seems like a a possible solution. thank you Jeroen!

Also found that this approach also works:

Select * From Students CROSS APPLY OpenJson (CommunicatorsJson) With (CommunicatorType nvarchar(100), UserName nvarchar(100))
where CommunicatorType = 3

Comment: @HotFrost: that gives different results if there are multiple objects with `CommunicatorType = 3`. If you know they are unique, the results are identical.

Comment: Also, it seems that your solution is a bit faster, Jeroen